# thread help TCL

Tags: multithreading, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a problem when I throw my script of two different ways

I set up ActiveState.

With tclsh86.exe , when I launch my script like that :

```
% source C:/Temp/thread.tcl
Thread 1: 0
Thread 1: 1
Thread 1: 2
Thread 1: 3
Thread 1: 4
Thread 1: 5
Thread 2: 0
Thread 2: 1
Thread 2: 2
Thread 2: 3
Thread 2: 4
Thread 2: 5
Thread 2: 6
Thread 2: 7
Thread 2: 8
Thread 2: 9
Thread 2: 10
```

with wish86.exe , when I launch my script like that :

```
(System32) 1 % source C:/Temp/thread.tcl
0
```

I don't understand , what is the problem ?
Thanks for your help

My code `thread.tcl` below :

```
package require Thread

# Thread1
set Thread1 [thread::create -joinable -preserved {

    proc exemple { {max 10} } {
    global w
        for {set i 0} {$i <= $max} {incr i} {
            puts "Thread 1: $i"
        }
    }

    thread::wait

}]

# Thread2
set Thread2 [thread::create -joinable -preserved {

    proc exemple { {max 10} } {
        for {set i 0} {$i <= $max} {incr i} {
            puts "Thread 2: $i"
        }
    }

    thread::wait

}]


thread::send -async $Thread1 [list exemple 5]
thread::send -async $Thread2 [list exemple 10]

thread::release -wait $Thread1
thread::release -wait $Thread2
```

Comment: Probably relates to how the faked console works. Might be an interaction between the inter-thread comms for the console and the inter-thread comms for `thread::release`.

Comment: The only way of executing in 'wish86.exe' ? : exec C:/Tcl/bin/tclsh86.exe C:/Temp/thread.tcl